# How can I convert an RSS feed to $wp_query->posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

Is it possible to convert RSS backwards in Wordpress. As in, rather than converting my posts to RSS, I want to convert RSS from another sites feed into the same format returned by $wp_query->posts to use in a Wordpress template in the same way I would use $wp_query->posts.

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: so you want to create posts from rss feed? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/import-external-rss-feed-as-posts

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into a solution using that - but I actually don't want them in the posts table, I just want to pull them into PHP in the same format that $wp_query->posts stores posts, so I can output them through the loop, just like posts that were in the DB.

Comment: you can also try asking at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/